# Desktop disappeared using GeForce 470 gtx

Tags: nvidia

I tried so many time to setup different driver on Ubuntu 12.10, but all of them are useless.
My Desktop disappear everytime and my loadingscreen, if I reboot, looks bad.

```
lspci | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF100 [GeForce GTX 470] (rev a3)
dpkg -l | grep -I nvidia

ii  bbswitch-dkms                             0.5-1~quantalppa1                                                           all          Interface for toggling the power on nVidia Optimus video cards
```

The name of my driver now is...

```
Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)
```

I tried this...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Purge ANY nvidia settings, go to nvidia website and download latest `.bin` driver pack. In order to install it you have to boot from `recovery options` and use command line.

Comment: Which command line?

Comment: reboot your system and choose the one labeled with `recovery ...`

Comment: Yes, i tried this option, but there i have to write in the console some comands which i don't know.

Luckly I tried the drivers from Synaptic Packet Manager and it works now.
I don't no why, because the same driver version I already tried out and last time it didn't work.
Maybe this is the same version but another build?

Thank you all for the answers.